# Is it possible to make (in-game) money through trading Ultimate Team players?

Tags: fifa-12

FIFA 12 Ultimate Team offers a cool auction system, where you can buy and sell players and  items either through bidding or fixed prices ("buy now").

I have a few related questions:

- Is it possible to make good money (coins) through clever trading? As you have to pay for every bid you make (you have a limited amount of bids, which you can refill with coins) and the prices probably regulate itself pretty good, I could imagine that it might not be really profitable, even if you know what you are doing.
- If it is, what are good strategies? Which items are easy to buy at low prices and sell at high prices? Is it better to look for rare players with low "buy now" prize for example, or buy stuff like balls? Will some items grow a lot of value over time?
- Are there times of the day where the prices are generally lower/higher on the market?
- Are even bad rare items worth keeping because there will be collectors who want a complete edition later?
- What's the best strategy to win an auction? Bid early to throw off others? Bid last minute?
- Any other tips?

I know an advice given here might well change the market and get useless in the process, but as not many FIFA players are on gaming.SE yet, I guess it's worth a shot. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to write a good answer that touches on all the points of your question. Some parts are speculative in nature anyway ... if you can narrow your question, I think it'll prompt better answers.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way for profit in trading is to buy golds, for no more than 300 coins.
75 rated will sell for 300
76- 304
77- 308
going up in fours everytime.
it dosent seem like much but if you do this in mass, everyday, this can rack up.

You could also try and sell expensive players, buying and selling on. 
But what you have to take into account is ea charge 5% of what you make!
for example if you bought a player for 300 if he only sold on auction for 300 you would have lost 15 coins so you have to take that into account.
Always watch for cheap buy nows!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to make a profit is to buy the 400 gold bronze pack and put the contents up for auction, using the lowest possible Buy Now price of 200. This means you only need to sell 2 of the 12 cards to break even and 3 to make a profit. There always seems to be a buyer for even the worst player cards (e.g. someone wants a particular nationality/club/favourite formation combination). You may even be able to sell the Rare card included in the pack for more than 200.